# how to set time zone in javascript new Date()

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using javascript new Date format. It is working well in android and windows but when I use it on iphone it outputs different result. How can I be able to solve the problem?

```
   var rawGetDate = "2019-02-01 00:00:00";
   var dateF = new Date(rawGetDate.replace(' ', 'T'));
   console.log(dateF);

OutPut in Androaid: Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600 
OutPut in Iphone: Mon Dec 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500
```

Comment: I doubt the output is like that on iPhone: 1 December 2018 was not a Monday. Did you mean 31 December?

Comment: Don't rely on `Date#toString()` Format it specifying a timezone. You can try the following for limited mileage. `console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver'}))` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Parameters or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Make sure to add the timezone indication to the string that you pass to `new Date`: for instance, for UTC, just add a "Z" at the end.

Comment: @trincot That will not print the date in the specified time zone, it will only read it in then print it in the local time zone

Comment: @JuanMendes, I know, but the output shows that, when looking at the printed timezone informations, they are not even the same date/time in the respective Date objects, otherwise they would have only differed with 1 hour. So also the loading part needs correction. There is clearly a difference in interpretation of the string when specified without timezone.

Comment: @trincot sorry my bad. you are right . its 31 December

Comment: And your original string is really 1 February? Or is it 1 January (2019-01-01)?

Comment: @trincot 2019-01-01

Comment: It is a pity that your question had two mistakes (so far). You really should pay more attention when asking a question ;-) One more: are the time parts really "00:00:00" on *both* devices, or does one have "23:00:00" or "01:00:00"?

Comment: Note that Safari incorrectly parses "2019-02-01T00:00:00" as UTC instead of local. Please **do not** use the built–in parser, a simple parser for an ISO–like format is 2 lines of code. The built–in parser has been unreliable for 20 years, that won't change anytime soon.